# How to effectively slice tabular data using data mapper and domain model?

Tags: php, oop, datamapper, domain-model

Let's say I have two tables: `Book` and `Category`. `Book` has a foreign key to `Category`. Book can only have on category. Let's say I want to display this table:

```
Book Title              | Category ID       | Category Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lord of the Rings       | 1                 | Fiction
Ender's Game            | 2                 | Science Fiction
Purpose Driven Life     | 3                 | Religious
```

With domain model and data mapper (Fowler's definition), we have `Book` and `Category` objects, each with their own mappers. The problem here is since both are separated entities, I end up with lots of queries run to display the above simple table:

```
$booksArray = $bookMapper->getTopTenBooks();
$viewData = array();

foreach ($booksArray as $book)
{
    $categoryID = $book->getCategoryID();
    $category = $categoryMapper->getByID($categoryID);
    $viewData[] = array(
        'book' => $book,
        'category' => $category
    );
}

return $view->load($viewData);
```

That's one query to get the list of books to display, along with many queries to get the appropriate category objects related to each books.

The thing is, with SQL, I can slice the data any way I want. I can actually get all the data I need with one query:

```
SELECT
    book.name, category.name
FROM
    book LEFT JOIN category ON (book.cat_id = category.id)
```

Can I use this SQL while still maintaining separation between presentation, data source and domain logic layer? If I can, how? How can we effectively slice data we wanted to display?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971798/data-mapper-and-relationships-implementation-strategies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Mapper just should have Map() method to map array to object, then you will be able to use SQL directly via PDO and then just map result to objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP but in many ORM's you can do it easily. For example in the EF4.0 you can use Include method to fetch to classes togheter: somthing like this: $bookMapper->GetAll().Include("Category"); and it runs one query but gets all objects. I think this separation is ralated completely to the ORM.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this without ORM, actually.

Comment: You need ORM to map your classes to tables, without ORM you should do it yourself, of course I don't recomend that.